# Realtime printing to SAS log during data step execution

Tags: sas

Is there a way to have `put` or `putlog` statements update the log window in realtime (ie. while the datastep is executing)?

I have a particularly long datastep executing and I want to be able to monitor progress as it is going.  In the example below I get the put statements written to the log when the datastep finishes executing.

Example Code:

```
data x;
  do i = 1 to 1000000 * 100;
    output;
    if mod(i,1000000 * 10) eq 0 then do;
      put i;
    end;
  end;
run;
```

**EDIT:**  I'm running SAS 9.4 TS1M4 on windows 10.  Just the regular editor, not EG.

Comment: Using what SAS client?  In old school interactive PC SAS it should work like you want. In Enterprise Guide you don't get the log back until the entire submission is complete.

Comment: I agree with @Quentin - We need to know your platform/client. I was just watching some real-time SAS log output from `PUTLOG` statements yesterday on the Windows PC SAS platform.

Comment: Updated with system info.

Comment: Hmmm. On win 7 works like you want on 9.3. But just tried 9.4M0 and the log does not get updated until the step completes. That's a surprise to me. Not sure if there is an option somewhere that might help.

Comment: @Quentin Thanks for clarifying that. I was under the impression that it worked the way you described as well and was surprised when I ran into this issue.  I looked through all the system options related to the log and didn't see anything in there.  This might be a question for SAS support.

Comment: Running 9.4 TS 1M2 on Windows 7 and I get immediate output.

Answer (score 0):

In Enterprise Guide: SAS should output messages, notes, warning and errors to the log after the execution of each datastep / procedure .

In Interactive Base SAS (9.4M5): You can use `putlog` statement and you can output messages and variable values to the log, see my sample code below:

```
data _NULL_;
%let ds=%sysfunc(datetime(),datetime23.);
putlog "Note: Start time is &ds.";
sleep_time=sleep(10,1);
putlog "Note: Another messge here " sleep_time=;
run;
```

Output in real time:

```
Note: Start time is 08MAY2018:13:58:26
Note: Another messge here sleep_time=10
```

Comment: I want the feedback during execution, not after execution is complete.

Comment: You can try the `putlog` statement but as Quentin commented above in EG you get the log post execution.  http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/lestmtsref/63323/HTML/default/viewer.htm#n05jha8tsrpanyn19m05ss7ltv6e.htm

Comment: I added code for real time execution logging. this wont work in EG

Comment: Just tried this and it does not give realtime output for me. Interactive Base SAS. 9.4 TS1M5. Windows 10.

Comment: Then you have to open a ticket with sas support at this pint. You can give them my code as example to replicate the issue; it works fine on my 9.4M5.

Comment: Yeah I'll open a ticket I guess although the request is kind of moot for me now.  As Quentin mentions above he sees the same behaviour depending on the SAS version so I'm not the only one this is affecting.